# jspm/ES6 compile error, packages location incorrect

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs, jspm

I'm having a difficult time getting the `jspm_packages` to work correctly in my `jspm` configuration in my `packages.json`. I'm writing an app in EM6 (babel engine).

I have a gulp file that places my ES6 javascript to a folder called `.tmp/scripts`:

```
gulp.task('transpile:app', ['templates'], function() {
  return gulp.src('app/scripts/**/*.js')
    .pipe($.babel({ sourceMap: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/scripts'));
});
```

And then a bundle task that is supposed to convert the files in `.tmp` into a folder called `dist`:

```
// Bundle javascripts
gulp.task('bundle:app', function() {
  return gulp.src('')
    .pipe($.shell('jspm bundle-sfx app dist/scripts/app.js --minify --skip-source-maps'));
});
```

This is where is fails.

Running `jspm bundle-sfx app dist/scripts/app.js --minify --skip-source-maps'` prompts this error:

```
warn jspm_packages must be specified in the package.json within the baseURL for paths to resolve correctly.
     Building the single-file sfx bundle for app...

err  Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/connorblack/git/**********/jspm_packages/github/marionettejs/backbone.marionette@2.4.2.js'
         at Error (native)
```

The odd thing is that this file path for `jspm_packages` is looking two directories above where it should be, thus prompting the `ENOENT` error.

I dove a little into the docs, and found that you can set a `"packages"` attribute in your `package.json`, which is what I have done, and this is what my current file looks like:

```
...
"jspm": {
    "directories": {
      "baseURL": ".tmp/scripts",
      "lib": "app",
      "packages": "jspm_packages"
    },
...
```

I've tried multiple variations, but they all end up with a similar error. Prefixing `../../` steps further up my file system, but since the command is already looking two directories above, this doesn't help.

As you would expect, removing the attribute entirely from my `package.json` removes the warning and changes the `ENOENT`:

```
     Building the single-file sfx bundle for app...

err  Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/connorblack/git/********/*********/skeleton/.tmp/scripts/jspm_packages/github/marionettejs/backbone.marionette@2.4.2.js'
         at Error (native)
```

where it now appears to be looking for the `jspm_packages` folder below my `baseURL` (`.tmp/scripts`), which is where my gulp process places my app's scripts before converting from ES6 to normal JS.

I'm at my wit's end here. I can't seem to get the `jspm` process to correctly find the `jspm_packages` and thus I can't compile my app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try `jspm bundle-sfx main dist/scripts/app.js --minify --skip-source-maps` instead?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar problem, 
when I was trying

```
jspm bundle app.js app/app.bundle.js
```

But I then changed

```
  "jspm": {
    "directories": {
      "baseURL": "app",
      "packages": "jspm_packages"
    },
```

to this ..

```
  "jspm": {
    "directories": {
      "baseURL": "app",
      "packages": "app/jspm_packages"
    },
```

and the bundling started to work ...